# Combine many 2D textures into one and write text on it in Unity (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, draw, texture2d

I have not found solution for my problem.

I want to combine few textures (one under another, they won't overlap) and then write a text on one of them. So basically I would like to set some render target, draw there few textures and text and then save it to final texture. Of course I need to do it during run-time from script.

What is the best way to do it in Unity 5.0? (script is in C#)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with 
[target texture](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-targetTexture.html)

Comment: Isn't that an overkill? There is no simpler solution for combining few Images into one 2D texture in run-time?

Comment: Yo can add few rendertotextures how you need, 1 for overlap all and combine in 1 image or more than 1 if you need more than 1 final texture.